# Pie chart from count of values (showing the percentage)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like below-

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Fully Paid',1,1],
    ['Fully Paid',1,1],
    ['Fully Paid',1,0],
    ['Defaulted',1,0],
    ['Defaulted',1,0]
], columns=['LoanStatus', 'B', 'C'])
```

I am looking to plot this in a pie chart showing 60% of loan status is fully paid while 40% is defaulted. I am able to do this in a count plot but unable to do it in a pie chart -

```
COUNT PLOT: 

sns.countplot(x="LoanStatus",data=df)
```

EXPECTED:

A pie chart showing how many values are there with both the loan status along with the percentage.

Comment: Note that seaborn doesn't create pie charts, as seaborn's author considers those to be unfit for statistical visualization. See e.g. [Why you shouldn’t use pie charts](https://scc.ms.unimelb.edu.au/resources/data-visualisation-and-exploration/no_pie-charts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this to get the pie plot. Adjust the `fmt` if you want to show the value and percentage differently.

```
#df.LoanStatus.
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Fully Paid',1,1],
    ['Fully Paid',1,1],
    ['Fully Paid',1,0],
    ['Defaulted',1,0],
    ['Defaulted',1,0]
], columns=['LoanStatus', 'B', 'C'])

total = df['LoanStatus'].value_counts().values.sum()

def fmt(x):
    return '{:.1f}%\n{:.0f}'.format(x, total*x/100)

plt.pie(df['LoanStatus'].value_counts().values, labels=df['LoanStatus'].value_counts().index, autopct=fmt)
```

[image]

Additional info - The `def fmt()` is a function which will be called for each entry while plotting. The value `x` will be the input which is the auto percent calculated (3/5*100=60 and 2/5*100=40). There are some more examples of using this [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html). The Total is calculated to get the sum of defaulted+FullyPaid (5). For each label, the returned value is basically in the string which is the input value x with 1 decimal place and a percentage symbol after it (`{:.1f}%`), then `\n` which is a newline character followed by the calculated field (total*x/100) which is in the format of a whole number with no decimals (`{:.0f}`). If you need more information on the string formatting options, you can find it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay. I am new to Python, can you explain this  : def fmt(x):
    return '{:.1f}%\n{:.0f}'.format(x, total*x/100)

Comment: Hi @Chandeep - Added some more info for your reference. Check out the Additional Info section in the answer

Answer (score 10):

Use custom function with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for percentages with counts in same pie graph:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/71515035/2901002
def autopct_format(values):
        def my_format(pct):
            total = sum(values)
            val = int(round(pct*total/100.0))
            return '{:.1f}%\n({v:d})'.format(pct, v=val)
        return my_format

s = df['LoanStatus'].value_counts()
plt.pie(s,labels = s.index, autopct=autopct_format(s))
#pandas only alternative
#s.plot.pie(autopct=autopct_format(s))
```

[image]